# How to put line-breaks in Yii2 validation rules messages

Tags: php, yii2, message, line-breaks, yii2-validation

I need to break a long message used in Yii2 validation rule.

I tried like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'required', 'message' => 'long message first line here'."<br>".PHP_EOL.'long message last line here'],
    ];
}
```

but the `<br>` appears in the message and the line doesn't break where I need.

Just to be clear, what I get is:

```
 long message first line here<br>long message last line here
```

and not:

```
 long message first line here
 long message last line here
```

Anyone who can help with this? I'd be really grate! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved adding this to ActiveForm::begin

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([

        'fieldConfig' => [
            'errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block', 'encode' => false],
    ],

]); ?>
```

and with a simple `<br />`

```
 [['username'], 'required', 'message' => 'long message first line here <br />long message last line here'],
```

Comment: Oh yeah! Accepted as the solution! I was trying to use [encodeErrorSummary](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$encodeErrorSummary-detail) for this `'encodeErrorSummary' => false` but, I can't understand why, it seems useless ??